# Django EmailField and full email address with first and last name

Tags: django, email

I would like to use the EmailField in a form. However, instead of only storing

```
support@acme.com
```

I want to store

```
"ACME Support" <support@acme.com>
```

The reason is, that when I send email, I would like a "friendly name" to appear.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Django's email field, and then use a property to render the friendly name in the email.

```
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MyModel(models.Model):
    email_address = models.EmailField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

    @property
    def friendly_email(self):
        return mark_safe(u"%s <%s>") % (escape(self.fullname), escape(self.email_address))
```

Comment: Where is that `escape` function defined?

Comment: And I'm assuming that `mark_safe` is the one from `django.utils.safestring` :) Please update the answer so newbies and newcomers don't get puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

Why not store the friendly name in a separate CharField? Alternatively, you could subclass the EmailField and build your own validation. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#howto-custom-model-fields

Comment: I'm going down this route. However, this is more me wondering if the EmailField can do it, or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The EmailField is basically a CharField but only validates against plain email adresses--no names or angle brackets. So, no, you're not doing anything wrong.